# How can I add a toolbar in the toolbarpanel programmatically?

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I want to add my `ToolBar` inside the `ToolBarPanel` in codebehind.
I saw one example of `Button` & `Canvas` panel.

Here is the code:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(newButton, containerPoint.X - objectPoint.X);
Canvas.SetTop(newButton, containerPoint.Y - objectPoint.Y);
```

How can I achive samething with `ToolBar` & `ToolBarPanel`instead of using `Canvas` & `Button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you gave is not adding the button to canvas, it sets extension properties that specify coordinates the button will be located at, if it is placed on `Canvas` panel.

`ToolBarPanel` is a primitive panel used by `ToolBar` to arrange its items. Unless you want to customize behavior you should be just using `ToolBar` optionally placing it into `ToolBarTray`.

`ToolBar` is an `ItemsControl` (just like `ListBox` for example), so to add a button from code, add it to panel's `Items` collection:

```
toolbar.Items.Add(newButton);
```